# How to sort char array alphabetically without "sort" function?

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a program that passes a predefined char array to a function that sorts the array alphabetically. I just don't know where to start, I need a function that sorts an array with the c++ sort function.

Comment: So - with or without?

Comment: Is this a homework problem where you're supposed to write a sort routine yourself?  Or something else?

Comment: You should talk to your teacher if you do not understand the assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to do it *without* `std::sort`, then there are a few different sorting algorithms that you could implement. Here is an example with [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort):

```
#include <iostream>

void sort(char* arr, int sz)
{
  for (int i = 1; i < sz; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < sz-i; j++)
    {
      if (arr[j] > arr[j+1])
      {
        int temp = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[j+1];
        arr[j+1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
}


int main() {
    const int SIZE = 6;
    char arr[SIZE] = {'a', 'd', 'r', 'b', 'c', 'e'};
    sort(arr, SIZE);
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every programming course i've taken has suggested you use the bubble sort method for these types of tasks, link to example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/

Answer (score 0):

As chars have their corresponding integer values [(look at ASCII Table)](http://www.asciitable.com/), you can use any sorting algorithm to sort an array of chars.

The simplest sorting algorithm (effective for small arrays) would be bubble sort, but you can also implement easily e.g. selection sort or insertion sort. If you look for faster algorithms (and more complex than former), take a look at merge sort, quick sort or heap sort.

Comment: If he is sorting ASCII chars then the range is limited and a counting sort would be linear time https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort